# how to disable datepicker without changing the style

Tags: wpf, xaml, datepicker

I want to disable datepicker for user,because I want to compute it from another information, but when I disable property for datepicker the color of datepicker changes to gray.

I don't want to change the style of datepicker. how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IsHitTestVisible` Property

```
<DatePicker IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
```

Hope it helps